# Adding hive jdbc dependency breaks Glassfish deployment

Tags: java, hadoop, jdbc, hive, glassfish

I'm building a Java webapp that needs to access Hive through JDBC, deployed on a Glassfish.

Once the hive jdbc maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
    <artifactId>hive-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

is added, deployment breaks and Glassfish gives the following exception:

Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : CDI deployment failure:WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Injector with qualifiers @Default at injection point [BackedAnnotatedParameter] Parameter 1 of [BackedAnnotatedConstructor] @Inject public org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebAppFilter(Injector) at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.webapp.RMWebAppFilter.(RMWebAppFilter.java:0) . Please see server.log for more details.

Comment: Which version of Glassfish do you use?

Comment: I'm using GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1 (build 1). The issue seems to have something to do with guava version having to be updated. I tried excluding them from my project, but I think I'll have to upgrade it on Glassfish itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the issue by

- Updating from Glassfish 4.1(1) to Glassfish 4.1(13). However this did not on itself solve the issue.
- On Glassfish's deploy screen in the admin console I disabled Implicit CDI Discovery.

Comment: where we can find CDI Discovery in admin console?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a dependency issue with the libs provived by **Glassfish 4.1.1 (1)**.

It works in **Glassfish 4.1 (13)**. If possible, you should use this version. 
You can download it here: https://glassfish.java.net/download-archive.html

Comment: Will try upgrading to (13) and get back to this asap.

Comment: Updated to Glassfish 4.1 (13) and still have the same issue. I take out the hive jdbc dependency and it deploys with no issues instantly.

Answer (score 1):

Hive-jdbc has some unfortunate dependencies (javax.*, jetty etc).
Your error comes from a transitively included YARN webapp.

Try to slim down the Maven dependencies of hive-jdbc,
as some dependencies like YARN do not belong in a JDBC driver.,